# Sending email issuse on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, sendgrid

I have a rails application deployed on heroku.

I have the `sendgrid:free` addon on heroku as well.

I am sending email from my app but I am getting these errors:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more

Here are the relevant parts of my `config/production.rb` :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'book-post.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "25",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  :password       => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com'
}
```

This is my `config/action_mailer.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'book-post.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { 
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net", 
  :port => "25", 
  :authentication => :plain, 
  :user_name => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"], 
  :password => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"], 
  :domain => 'heroku.com' 
}
```

I have tried using `:port => '587'` but it did not help.

Comment: can you show us your config action_mailer?

Comment: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'book-post.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "25",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  :password       => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com'
}

Comment: Try with `:port => 587`